# Why maven deploys jar-with-dependencies twice?

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I use maven-assembly-plugin to build jar with dependencies, then I want to deploy it into a Nexus repository.

When I use `mvn deploy` everything works great, but when I try to use `mvn install deploy` all other modules also deploy well, but jar-with-dependencies deploys twice.

Deploy plugin's configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <deployAtEnd>true</deployAtEnd>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Assembly plugin's configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
  <descriptorRefs>
    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
  </descriptorRefs>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>com.test.Main</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Question**: Does anyone know why it is uploaded twice?

Comment: deploy will automatically invoke install as part of the build lifecycle, so no need to invoke it explicitly again. Can you share some part of your pom if any further configuration on the deploy plugin is present?

Comment: Something must be wrong with your setup. Could you post your entire POM?

Comment: Yes, but it's just interesting why `mvn install deploy` deploys all jars correctly and only jar-with-dependencies twice. I've added maven plugins configurations.

Comment: Calling `mvn install deploy` does not make sense, cause the life cycle phases which are run by using `mvn install`  will also included if you call `mvn deploy` in result means that that all life cycle phase which run in `mvn install` will be repeated which is not needed.